# error while creating the database in jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a database on sdcard, and to create 2 tables in the database.

Whenever i try to run my app i am able to create the table and successfully inserting the value into it.

But each time when i try to run i will get an error saying "Error Processing sql: Undefined".

I am using the following code to create the database and table.

```
var db;

db = window.openDatabase("../../../mnt/sdcard/Database", "1.0", "school", 200000);

function createDb() {

    db.transaction(populateDB, success, errorCB);
}

// Populate the database
function populateDB(tx) {
    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FOLDER');
    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2 ');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOLDER (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , stdname UNIQUe )');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (stdname,joinedDate)');

}

// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
}

function success() {
    alert("created!");
    //console.log("Huray created");
}
```

How to avoid the error??

I am not getting any error in my logcat also.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when you specify database as only an alphanumeric string (say "testdb" or so)? If so, it may just be faulty error handling when accessing the sd card or so. Permissions problem, who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the db and call createDb() inside :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
    db = window.openDatabase("../../../mnt/sdcard/Database", "1.0", "school", 200000);
    createDb();

},false
);
```

Comment: Edited the answer,try this.

Comment: Doing it only after "deviceready" seems like a smart move in any case.

Comment: @Suhas_United it's still same. actually i was calling it after device ready only in my html page.